# javax.faces.FacesException . It is a exception belongs to Spring Security 3.x

Tags: java, spring, jsf, struct

I am developing an application using Struts 2.x. I am using Spring Security to provide security to my application. However, when I am not connect to the internet I always get an exception. If I have internet connect, there will be no exception. The exception is:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Can't parse configuration file:
jar:file:/home/dev7/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/UNHPM_5/WEB-INF/lib/skyway-spring-utils-7.1.3.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml:
Error at line 5 column 16: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of
element 'faces-config'.
```

I have also added the jar file `skyway-spring-utils-7.1.3.jar` to project but the exception remains when I am not connected to the internet. What may be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Probably this problem belongs to jar version miss-match.because it's create incompatibility between the DTD version.
- Another problem may be you have multiple versions of jar in your build-path.
- My suggestion is use maven to add the dependency jar